# Diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2\times S^1$

Tags: geometry, diffeomorphism

Let $M_c=\{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)\in \mathbb{R}^4 \ |\ x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_4=c\}.$

Prove that $M_c$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2\times S^1$ if $c\neq 0$ .

I tried to get a diffeomorphic mapping, but I couldn't think of anything.

Please tell me how to get the map.

Comment: Have you tried diagonalizing the quadratic form? Find the eigendecomposition of its matrix.

Comment: No. I don't know how that is related to the question I asked. Please tell me more details.

Comment: By diagonalizing, you can write $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_4=\lambda_1u_1^2+\lambda_2u_2^2+\lambda_3u_3^2+\lambda_4u_4^2$ in new coordinates, where $\lambda$s are the eigenvalues. You ought to end up with two positive and two negative eigenvalues, so you can rescale the coordinates to get $v_1^2+v_2^2-v_3^2-v_4^2$. Do you follow the reasoning up to that point? Do you know how to show the level sets of that are diffeomorphic to $S^2\times\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Your question is a bare problem statement with no context. Let me suggest that you look at our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [avoiding "I couldn't think of anything" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933), and on [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Comment: Why are eigenvalues two positive and two negative? I thought the matrix of the quadratic form is \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: @Rosalina That is one such matrix, but you ought to use a *symmetric* matrix because the form is symmetric and spectral theory applies to symmetric matrices. Average that matrix with its transpose.

Comment: @Lee Mosher
I am very sorry.
This question is the entrance exam to Tokyo Institute of Technology (graduate school) in 2020. I take the exam this year.
Any friends couldn't solve this problem, so I want you to help me.

Comment: The duplicate question I have found has an interesting connection with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3241799/textsl2-mathbbr-is-homeomorphic-to-s1-times-mathbbr2)